How to restore specific files from time machine to a different folder
I want to restore the keychain library from my older Mac, which I don't have anymore. But I don't want to overwrite the existing keychain. The Time Machine interface only lets me restore files in place. One would think the "restore to..." option would let me choose where to restore them, but it doesn't and just tries to overwrite everything. I can't empty/rename the directory beforehand because the directory.

Welcome to Ask Different. There are several keychain files by default across several libraries and some link to others explicitly - are you operating on a log in keychain or one of the others? What build is the macOS on which you’re trying to do a restore?

In the general case of keychains across user accounts and not specific macOS versions, I would use Finder and spotlight to copy the files to a folder of my choosing and then open and inspect these keychain files before attempting any restore if I was trying to merge items.
Only if I was sure I wanted the entire user folder and had a double checked backup of the current Mac would I try to restore an entire user folder from backup. There’s just too much that could go wrong in my experience to recommend what you’re trying.
Time Machine is safest when you restore onto a blank OS for these files as opposed to how it works very well for document-based file recovery at any time IMO. Library files are different and sometimes not as conducive to pick and place treatment.
